# Changeable input hidden field

Tags: php, html, input, hidden

I have one tricky problem about input=hidden field, with a value $_SESSION['userid']. Problem is, when someone opens firebug, he can easely change the value data... How can I prevent this?

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="ID" />
```

Comment: Adding Server side validation and checking. Welcome to userland, where nobody can be trusted

Comment: That is not possible. You cannot prevent that.

Answer (score 3):

You can't, you'll probably want to validate that $_POST['id'] === $_SESSION['userid'] after form submission to verify that you got the correct value there.

Answer (score 2):

Anything that sits on the client side (HTML, JavaScript...) can in theory be modified by the user. So the idea is to either NOT put any sensitive data on the client side, or at least double check on the server side.

In your example, you are using it seems a SESSION variable. Why do you need it on the client side? If this data is already in $_SESSION, maybe you can use it directly?
In your receiving code instead of reading `$_POST['id]` just read `$_SESSION['userid']` directly??

If you really need to re-send data (if so explain why), then on the server side check that what you get matches with the currently logged-in user (or what is currently in the session).

In one of my app that generated a form automatically, I simply ignored some of the fields in the server side, and replaced them by what I expected them to be no matter what - taken from my database or session variable.